# Mixed derivative finite difference

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-derivative, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

In my research work, I differentiated the following equation with respect to t

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=x(1-x)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-(\omega^2-2)u$$

to get

$$\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t^3}=x(1-x)\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t\,\partial x^2}-(\omega^2-2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}.$$

Differentiating again, with respect to t gives

$$\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial t^4}=x(1-x)\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial t^2\,\partial x^2}-(\omega^2-2)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}.$$

However, I have a problem representing $\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t\,\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial t^2\,\partial x^2}$ as central difference mixed derivative approximations. I understand that, for central difference

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{i,j}=\frac{u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}}{2\Delta x}$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)_{i,j}=\frac{u_{i+1,j}-2u_{i,j}+u_{i-1,j}}{(\Delta x)^2}$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{i,j}=\frac{u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j}}{\Delta t}$$

**My question is**: how do I derive $\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial t^2\,\partial x^2},\;\;\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t\,\partial x^2}, \;\; \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}\;\; \text{and} \;\; \frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t^3}$?

Comment: If I have well understood, you are interested in expressions for numerical differentiation of $\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial t^2\,\partial x^2},\;\;\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t\,\partial x^2}, \;\; \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}\;\; \text{and} \;\; \frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t^3}$?

Comment: @ Carlos Campos, you are right! I developed an algorithm that makes use of method of lines!

Comment: @ John Glenn, thank you very much for that!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to discretize $\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial t^4}$, $\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial t^3}$, etc.?  Why not discretize the original equation?

Comment: @  Kyle. I am working on a numerical method that makes use of 'method of lines'. Thus, I need those semi-discretizations. However, if you feel I should discretize all, then that will be fine!

Comment: @Omojola, I understand the basics of the MOL.  I would suggest that you apply MOL to $u_{tt} = x(1-x)u_{xx} - (\omega^2 - 2)u$, unless you have some compelling reason to differentiate the equation with respect to time.  The reason I suggest this is because you (presumably) only have two initial conditions-- $u(x,0)$ and $u_t(x,0)$.  Therefore, it doesn't really make sense to me to differentiate with respect to time... which would imply needing an additional initial condition.

Comment: @ Kyle. The method I derived makes use of method of lines. Hence, converting the PDE to ODE first and then semi-discretizing it. This process is done by employing the finite difference schemes. Thus, I would have $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=uk$ where $k$ is a constant matrix. So you see, I really need those schemes in my work.

Comment: @ Kyle. In response to "which would imply needing an additional initial condition" - yes, my code can automatically generate the additional initial conditions.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4378889/805029) help you in some way?